# Export Umbraco content to PDF

Tags: pdf, model-view-controller, export, umbraco

I have an Umbraco page and want to export a pdf file from the controller. How can i export easily to a pdf? I don't know how to do it in the best way.

I want to design the pdf by myself, that's important.

I already tried to solve this problem by using this code

```
// A path to export a report.
string reportPath = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PDF\\test.pdf";

// Create a report instance.
XtraReport report = new XtraReport();

// Get its PDF export options.
PdfExportOptions pdfOptions = report.ExportOptions.Pdf;

// Set PDF-specific export options.
pdfOptions.Compressed = true;
pdfOptions.ImageQuality = PdfJpegImageQuality.Low;
pdfOptions.NeverEmbeddedFonts = "Tahoma;Courier New";
pdfOptions.DocumentOptions.Application = "Test Application";
pdfOptions.DocumentOptions.Author = "DX Documentation Team";
pdfOptions.DocumentOptions.Keywords = "XtraReports, XtraPrinting";
pdfOptions.DocumentOptions.Subject = "Test Subject";
pdfOptions.DocumentOptions.Title = "Test Title";

// Export the report to PDF.
report.ExportToPdf(reportPath, pdfOptions);
```

but it won't work.

Thanks

Comment: Please add the code here, so everything is visible from this page.

Comment: Iet will assist in answering this if you provide more details on how this is not working. "it won't work" is a little nondescript!

Comment: It seems you are using devexpress components.  Do you have a license for these components?  If not, the code will never work.